# Aspect fit image in UISegmentedControl

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a `UISegmentedControl` control with 4 images in it. I would like these to scale with `Aspect fit`.

on a button there is `button.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit` that you could do, but i can't seem to get hold of the `imageView` for the segments.

How can this be done?
programmatically or storyboard doesn't matter, so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

You need to iterate all the UIImageView inside the segmentControl.

```
    segmentedControl.subviews.flatMap{$0.subviews}.forEach { subview in
        if let imageView = subview as? UIImageView, imageView.frame.width > 5 {
            imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        }
    }
```

Explain:

```
imageView.frame.width > 5
```

There are many different imageView inside the SegmentControl, so we check the width of UIImageView to ensure it is image of segment.